# Multiple ajax callback functions editing localStorage

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-services

I have a service 'UserData' that sends out multiple http requests. For each request's success handler, a function (in a controller) is called. This function prints out everything in local storage (for this example lets say 5 items) and deletes them all.

From my understanding of javascript everything is executed in a single thread. This means that even though there multiple callbacks being called at potentially the same time, they will be processed sequentially (one by one). Now when the first callback loops through localStorage and deletes all the items i would expect all subsequent callbacks to not print anything from localStorage since all items should be deleted already.

But when i test this theory, All 5 items in local storage are printed out for every callback. This may be more of a javascript question than an angular one but any insight would be appreciated.

Service:

```
app.factory('UserData', ['$http',
    function($http) {

        return {

            save: function(data, apiEndpoint, scope) {

                $http({method: 'PUT', url: apiEndpoint,

                    headers: { 
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }, 

                    data: data}).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                        scope.processFailedQueue();

                    }).
                    error(function(rdata, status, headers, config) {


                    });

            }

        };

    }

]);
```

Controller:

```
function baseFunctionController($scope, $location, $route, $http, contentService, UserData) {

    $scope.processFailedQueue = function() {

        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
            console.log(localStorage.key(i));
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
            localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
        localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(i));
    }
```

If the first iteration removes the item at position 0, then `localStorage.length` should immediately decrease, shifting all the items left, and moving the item that was in position 1 now into position 0.

But then `i++` increments `i` to 1, so on the next iteration you skip the removal of the item now at 0.  Repeat.

As a result, your loop only removes half of the items in storage!  To avoid this problem, try looping backwards:

```
    for (var i = localStorage.length; i--; ){
        localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(i));
    }
```